# Add columns values according to dates

Tags: r

I have a date column and a price column:

```
date = c(2012/12/12 00:00:00.000, 2012/12/12 00:00:00.000, 2012/12/12 00:00:00.000, 2012/12/19 00:00:00.000, 2012/12/19 00:00:00.000, 2013/01/02 00:00:00.000, 2013/01/09 00:00:00.000, 2013/01/19 00:00:00.000, 2013/02/05 00:00:00.000, 2013/02/19 00:00:00.000, 2013/02/26 00:00:00.000, 2013/03/05 00:00:00.000, 2013/03/12 00:00:00.000, 2013/03/20 00:00:00.000, 2013/03/26 00:00:00.000, 2013/04/02 00:00:00.000, 2013/04/09 00:00:00.000, 2013/04/16 00:00:00.000, 2013/04/23 00:00:00.000, 2013/04/30 00:00:00.000, 2013/05/08 00:00:00.000, 2013/06/04 00:00:00.000, 2013/06/29 00:00:00.000, 2013/07/29 00:00:00.000, 2013/08/26 00:00:00.000, 2013/09/19 00:00:00.000, 2013/10/14 00:00:00.000, 2013/10/21 00:00:00.000, 2013/10/30 00:00:00.000, 2013/11/05 00:00:00.000, 2013/11/13 00:00:00.000, 2013/11/20 00:00:00.000, 2013/11/26 00:00:00.000, 2013/12/03 00:00:00.000, 2013/12/10 00:00:00.000, 2013/12/19 00:00:00.000, 2013/12/26 00:00:00.000, 2014/01/03 00:00:00.000, 2014/01/09 00:00:00.000, 2014/01/24 00:00:00.000, 2014/01/31 00:00:00.000, 2014/02/06 00:00:00.000, 2014/02/13 00:00:00.000, 2014/02/20 00:00:00.000, 2014/03/01 00:00:00.000, 2014/03/08 00:00:00.000, 2014/03/14 00:00:00.000, 2014/03/28 00:00:00.000, 2014/04/03 00:00:00.000, 2014/04/10 00:00:00.000, 2014/04/25 00:00:00.000, 2014/05/02 00:00:00.000, 2014/05/09 00:00:00.000, 2014/06/28 00:00:00.000, 2014/07/05 00:00:00.000, 2014/07/23 00:00:00.000)

price = rep(23.5, 56)
```

Each date is a transaction date, and price is just a price of a product. I want to calculate the amount of money spend in the last 12 weeks. This means that everytime there is a transaction date, I count 12 weeks backwards. I can calculate the cumulative amount:

df = data.table(date = date, price = price)
   df[, quantity.csum := cumsum(price)]

I have the impression it is quite simple, but I can not find a way to do it by 12 weeks (or any amount of weeks I decide later).

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define a "period" column which defines the time period you want to consider and use e.g. `aggregate`

```
date <- c("2012/12/12 00:00:00.000", "2012/12/12 00:00:00.000", 
          "2012/12/12 00:00:00.000", "2012/12/19 00:00:00.000", "2012/12/19 00:00:00.000", 
          "2013/01/02 00:00:00.000", "2013/01/09 00:00:00.000", "2013/01/19 00:00:00.000", 
          "2013/02/05 00:00:00.000", "2013/02/19 00:00:00.000", "2013/02/26 00:00:00.000", 
          "2013/03/05 00:00:00.000", "2013/03/12 00:00:00.000", "2013/03/20 00:00:00.000")
price <- rep(23.5, 14)
period <- c(rep("period1",5), rep(c("period2", "period3", "period4"), each=3))
df <- data.frame(date=date, price=price, period=period)
df
                      date price  period
1  2012/12/12 00:00:00.000  23.5 period1
2  2012/12/12 00:00:00.000  23.5 period1
3  2012/12/12 00:00:00.000  23.5 period1
4  2012/12/19 00:00:00.000  23.5 period1
5  2012/12/19 00:00:00.000  23.5 period1
6  2013/01/02 00:00:00.000  23.5 period2
7  2013/01/09 00:00:00.000  23.5 period2
8  2013/01/19 00:00:00.000  23.5 period2
9  2013/02/05 00:00:00.000  23.5 period3
10 2013/02/19 00:00:00.000  23.5 period3
11 2013/02/26 00:00:00.000  23.5 period3
12 2013/03/05 00:00:00.000  23.5 period4
13 2013/03/12 00:00:00.000  23.5 period4
14 2013/03/20 00:00:00.000  23.5 period4

aggregate(price~period, data=df, sum)
   period price
1 period1 117.5
2 period2  70.5
3 period3  70.5
4 period4  70.5
```

EDIT :

```
df <- data.frame(date=date, price=price)
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date)
df[df$date1 >= "2012-12-12" & df$date1 <= "2012-12-19", "period"] <- "period 1"
df[df$date1 >= "2013-01-02" & df$date1 <= "2013-02-19", "period"] <- "period 2"
df[df$date1 >= "2013-02-26" & df$date1 <= "2013-03-20", "period"] <- "period 3"

aggregate(price~period, data=df, sum)
```

EDIT 2:

```
twelve_weeks <- 7*12 # Seven days in one week
df$date1 - twelve_weeks # Vector containing dates twelve
                        # weeks before each transaction dates
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! But a quick question, how do I define the period? I should count the amount of weeks between transaction to know to which period each date corresponds to.

Comment: Using `as.Date` you can convert your variable into a `Date` class which better handles date and time. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I saw your edit, and I see now that I am mistaken in my explanation. I need the money spent in the last 12 weeks, i.e., every time there is a new transaction date, I count 12 weeks. It is kind of rollover quantity.

Comment: I'm not sure to get everything but once your variable as a `Date` class you can easily define a period of twelve weeks starting or ending at a specific date. See the 2nd edit.